# Identify this avian courtship ritual

Tags: ornithology

The female drops a twig from high up on a tree and the males have to catch it midair. The female is checking if the males can catch things midair because this species nests on cliffs, and the chicks may fall to their deaths while learning to fly. Apparently, skilled males can catch the chicks midair.

Which species is it?

Comment: Where did you hear about it?  Do you know anything else about the bird?  It sounds a lot like an eagel, but it's hard to validate that it's the only bird that exhibits those patterns.

Comment: So eagles actually do that? Do you have a source? My friend says this happened in a documentary we watched together, but I have no recollection of ever seeing such a thing.